# How to prevent activity restart on device orientation change only for some duration and not all the time

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation-changes

In my activity, there is a lot of processing done in oncreate() like opening a database, writing files on the sd card. But all of this heavy processing happens only once when the activity is launched the first time and not after that. I am using an Async task to achieve this.

I am using the following code to prevent activity restart during device configuration change.

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                }
                else {
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                }
```

I wish to disable activity restart due to change in device orientation only once when the initial setup takes place and after that, I want to enable activity restart. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your activity tag in manifest file

android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

Comment: while this might work, this is a very bad practice to follow just because if you turn the device your application will crash. It is like healing symptom instead of the cause.

Comment: Note: Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last-resort. Please read Handling Runtime Changes for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: which is exactly what i said.

Comment: thanks vipin. but i would like to avoid using this. Also, i want to handle config changes only for sometime and not thereafter, if that can be done

Comment: I could not find any other solution easier than this. And have faced no problem in my app till now by doing this. So, am accepting this answer.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"if you can't beat them, join them" they said. Therefore, you should better organize you application workflow.

Keep your UI-related operations in the standard lifecycle methods (onCreate, onStart, etc.) and demand the long-lasting operation to other threads.

Please take a look to AsyncTask and IntentService classes, they will be very useful to you.

To summarize, it is often easier to adapt your code to the underlying system than forcing the system itself to follow your will

Comment: The OP states in their post they already know about AsyncTask

Comment: he knows about it but he does not know how to properly keep a reference to it when configuration changes. It's like i know about Diesel engines just because i have heard of them. whatever.

Comment: thanks.. I would surely think on similar lines and try to improve my code.

Comment: sure! in a long run you will find much more benefit from this approach. Remember that it is pretty annoying for an user to rotate the device with the application stuck!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be calling `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR)`. However I'd better consider what STT LCU is saying. Here are some articles I'd suggest start with:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#lifecycle